# Dockershim deprecation in kubernetes - DIND on containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

Currently we are using [dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/)(we are not mounting docker.sock from host) on kuberenetes to build container images and also to run containers inside container for running unit tests. With Dockershim deprecation in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dockershim-faq/), I am trying to analyze whether dind will still work on kubernetes without dockershim and with containerd runtime.

I tried running dind pod on gcp and aws eks with containerd container runtime with kubernetes 1.21 release. It worked without any issue in privileged mode. But I am confused how it can even work as dind is docker in docker and not docker in containerd. I did some research, but still cannot figure out how this works and whether it will work with kubernetes 1.24 release. Can someone help?

I used below spec for testing on kubernetes with containerd runtime

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: dind
  name: dind
spec:
  containers:
  - image: docker:20.10.12-dind
    name: dind
    ports:
    - containerPort: 2375
    securityContext:
     privileged: true
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
      value: ''
  - name: client
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: tcp://localhost:2375
```

[AWS userguide regarding dockershim deprecation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dockershim-deprecation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the name docker-in-docker it's actually docker-in-any-compatible-CRI-runtime. This clause confirms it (source https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dockershim-faq/#will-my-existing-docker-images-still-work):

> Yes, the images produced from docker build will work with all CRI implementations. All your existing images will still work exactly the same.

So if you aren't using `/var/run/docker.sock` you're good.

Comment: I am aware that existing docker images will work. My question is whether we can still build docker images on Kubernetes using dind approach i mentioned in the description

Comment: I got it, yeah. I meant that if the dind image continues working (sure, using the privileged mode), then why should building images using it stop working?

Comment: my question was to better understand how docker-in-docker works as we use this to build lots of container images and to better prepare for it. My question is similar to one posted on kubernetes forums https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/questions-concerning-dockershim-deprecation/18985/2.